# empty array in IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am trying to add a checkbox in header for all rows selection in jsgrid as shown [here](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/837). It is working fine. But, instead putting all the code in a single page, I tried to put these functions inside IIFE as follows.

```
var jsgridCheckBox = (function() {
    var selectedItems = [];
    var selectItem = function(item) {
        selectedItems.push(item);
        ...
    };

    var unselectItem = function(item) {
        selectedItems = $.grep(selectedItems, function(i) {
            return i !== item;
        });
        ...
    };

    var selectAllCheckBox = function(item) {
        selectedItems = [];
        if (this.checked) {
            ...
        }
    };

    return {
        selectedItems: selectedItems,
        selectItem: selectItem,
        unselectItem: unselectItem,
        selectAllCheckBox: selectAllCheckBox
    }
})();
```

In JSGrid,

```
$(function() {
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid(
        ...
        fields: [
            itemTemplate: function(_, item) {
                return $("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox").attr("class", "singleCheckbox")
                    .prop("checked", $.inArray(item, jsgridCheckBox.selectedItems) > -1)
                    .on("change", function() {
                        $(this).is(":checked") ? jsgridCheckBox.selectItem(item) : jsgridCheckBox.unselectItem(item);
                    });
            }
            ...
        ]
    });
});
```

And after selecting checkbox(s), when I try to call it as below

```
var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Reject": rejectRequest,
    }
});

function rejectRequest() {
    alert(jsgridCheckBox.selectedItems.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsgridCheckBox.selectedItems.length; i++) {
        alert(jsgridCheckBox.selectedItems[i].some_id);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

it always returns `0`. Is it that the `jsgridCheckBox` always returns a fresh instance? How can I maintain the state of the array in IIFE?

Comment: Can you please replicate this somewhere?

Comment: Where is the code that actually uses this? Also, what is `this` in `if(this.checked)`?

Comment: @Phil, edited my question

Comment: Not seeing anything that calls `selectItem()` which is the only method that pushes anything in to `selectedItems`. Why would you expect anything to be in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a private variable inside the closure there, `selectedItems`, and you also have a property on the object called `selectedItems`. That will cause confusion. The initial value of the *property* is just the empty array. When checkboxes are selected or unselected, `selectedItems` gets *reassigned* with your `=`; it's no longer referring to your original array. The reference will only remain if the array in question gets *mutated* (which isn't a great idea to rely on).

You can define a *getter* function that returns the current reference to the array:

```
var jsgridCheckBox = (function(){
  var selectedItems = [];
  var selectItem = function(item) {
    selectedItems.push(item);
  };

  var unselectItem = function(item) {
    selectedItems = $.grep(selectedItems, function(i) {
      return i !== item;
    });
  };

  var selectAllCheckBox = function(item) {
    selectedItems = [];
    if(this.checked) {
    }
  }; 

  return{
    getSelectedItems : () => selectedItems,
    selectItem : selectItem,
    unselectItem : unselectItem,
    selectAllCheckBox :selectAllCheckBox 
  }
})();
```

Or you can always refer to the array as a property of the object, rather than as a standalone variable:

```
var jsgridCheckBox = (function(){
  var selectItem = function(item) {
    this.selectedItems.push(item);

  };

  var unselectItem = function(item) {
    this.selectedItems = $.grep(this.selectedItems, function(i) {
      return i !== item;
    });

  };

  var selectAllCheckBox = function(item) {
    this.selectedItems = [];
    if(this.checked) {

    }
  }; 

  return{
    selectedItems : [],
    selectItem : selectItem,
    unselectItem : unselectItem,
    selectAllCheckBox :selectAllCheckBox 
  }
})();
```

Comment: Good catch on the reference issue but I'd keep it the way OP has it but empty out the array with `selectedItems.length = 0`. Won't `this` in the functions be bound to the function and not the object?

Comment: Thanks, will try that out.

Comment: @Phil The calling context of the functions *should* be the `jsgridCheckBox` in the code posted so far, right? But yes, keeping track of the `this`s is annoying. Edited to show another option